# Checking if vim is installed successfully in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: bash, scripts, vim

I am a newbie in linux,maybe it's a silly question but could not make it though.

I have ubuntu 12.04 installed without GNOME and now as i wanted to know more about linux am facing few queries.

I want to write a script which will automate few daily task.

Now I have opened terminal and selected BASH(default) by typing `echo $SHELL` to write a script I found that a editor is the choise like vi or vim.

Firstly can I do script in open terminal/BASH without installing vim. I have installed vim with the following cmd `sudo apt-get install vim`.

How to check from CLI whether **vim** is successfully installed and where can I find the files in the directories.

Comment: Try with opening a simple text file with vim. `vim [FILENAME]`

Comment: this will check if its installed. but y use vim rather than just using BASH. and as vim is editor like notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should know that vim or vi or gedit are just text editors....

You can write a script without using using the text editors, i.e you can just write your script directly in your bash shell.. but you have lastly to redirect it to a file in order to call the script later.

It's better to use a text editor to do such thing and to make easy to edit and maintain your script..

now to know if vim is installed in your system *or whatever other application*  you can use the following command `apt-cache policy <package-name>`

Check the answer in the [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87415/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-specific-program-is-installed) for more details

Comment: 1 more thing,in which directory can i find the vim files like we find in c:program files

Comment: @black use the command `whereis vim`   to locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command

Answer (score 2):

```
vim -- version
```

should do the job.
if vim is installed, it shows you the version of vim, else it asks you to install it.